# Adding foreign key to kdb existing table

Tags: foreign-keys, kdb

I need to add a foreign key to a table that I have imported using a csv

```
table:("SSSSSSSSSFFFFSSSSSFSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS"; enlist ",") 0: 
`:table.csv
```

I do not want to have to redefine the whole table. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```html
q)p:([p:`p1`p2`p3`p4`p5`p6]name:`nut`bolt`screw`screw`cam`cog;color:`red`green`blue`red`blue`red;weight:12 17 17 14 12 19;city:`london`paris`rome`london`paris`london)
q)sp:([]s:`s1`s1`s1`s1`s4`s1`s2`s2`s3`s4`s4`s1;p:`p$`p1`p2`p3`p4`p5`p6`p1`p2`p2`p2`p4`p5;qty:300 200 400 200 100 100 300 400 200 200 300 400)
q)
q)update `p$p from `sp
`sp
q)meta sp
c  | t f a
---| -----
s  | s    
p  | s p  
qty| j
```

Defining a foreign key is similar to enumerating/casting and therefore an overload of $ is used.

`sp means that the table is updated in place.

Comment: Is there no way to do it without redefining the table? My table has over 600,000 rows and about 30 columns

Comment: Hi Michael, apologies I'm just seeing this now. What do you mean by redefining? The update above creates the foreign key in place and doesn't make a copy of the table in memory. Thanks, Jamie